# I need to calculate and add two points between two given points how do i use a formula?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the question before I got this method:

```
private static List<PointF> ExtendPoints(
    PointF pt1,
    PointF pt4,
    int numberOfPoints)
{
    extendedPoints.Add(pt1);

    for (double d = 1; d < numberOfPoints - 1; d++)
    {
        double a = (Math.Max(pt1.X, pt4.X) - Math.Min(pt1.X, pt4.X)) * d / (double)(numberOfPoints - 1) + Math.Min(pt1.X, pt4.X);
        double b = (Math.Max(pt1.Y, pt4.Y) - Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt4.Y)) * d / (double)(numberOfPoints - 1) + Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt4.Y);
        var pt2 = new PointF((float)a, (float)b);
        extendedPoints.Add(pt2);
    }

    extendedPoints.Add(pt4);
    return extendedPoints;
}
```

But the results are not right.

This is how I'm using the method:

```
for (int i = 1; i < clouds.Count; i++)
{
    extendedPoints = ExtendPoints(clouds[i - 1], clouds[i], 2);
}
```

`clouds` and `extendedPoints` are both `List<PointF>` type.

The formula in the method should be: `(n-1)*m + n`.
For example:

Lets say the length of the `clouds` list is `2`.
I have in `clouds` two points:

```
Index 0: X = 120 Y = 125

Index 1: X = 130 Y = 135
```

Now the method get the two points and the number 2 that means the method should implant between each two given points another two points:

So now `extendedPoints` should be for example:

```
Index 0: X = 120 Y = 125
Index 1: X = 126 Y = 127
Index 2: X = 128 Y = 129
Index 3: X = 130 Y = 135
```

Now lets say the list `clouds` length is `3` so the method will get each time two points and implant between them new 2 points:

So lets say `clouds` contains `3` points now:

```
Index 0: X = 100 Y = 125
Index 1: X = 130 Y = 147
Index 2: X = 150 Y = 160
```

So between index `0` and index `1` the method implants `2` points, so now it's `4`.
Then between index `1` and index `2` the method implant another new two points.
So together `extendedPoints` should contain now `7` points.

Just like the formula:

```
(n-1)*m + n
```

`n` is the length of the original list `clouds`. `m` is the number of points the method should implant between two points.

So if the `clouds` would have `5` points: `(5-1)*2 + 5 = 13`
And if `clouds` would contain `10` points: (10-1)*2 + 10 = 28

Now how do I implement this in the method?

The rules:

1. Get two points implanted between the two points another new 2 points.
2. Keep the points order first `pt1` then two new points and in the end `pt4`.
3. Using the formula: `(n-1)*m + n`

The way the method is now it's not giving the right result. For example if the `clouds` contains `2` points and the method should create `2` new points the list `extendedPoints` should contain `4` points:

```
(2-1)*2 + 2 = 4
```

But I'm getting `2` points, `extendedPoints` contains only `2` points. And that's wrong!

How do I implement it using the formula?

More explanation:

If I give two points: first iteration `pt1` and `pt4` then implant between them two new points.
In this first iteration `pt1` is contained in `clouds` at index `0` and `pt4` is in `clouds` at index `1`.

In the next iteration `pt1` should be in `clouds` at index `1` and `pt4` at index `2`, and implant two new points between them.

Then next iteration, `pt1` at index `2` and `pt4` at index `3`.
And so on, depending on the `clouds` list length.

And when adding the points to the list, the method should always add first `pt1` and then the two new points, then `pt4`.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You're asking about some form of interpolation but without giving details about what kind of interpolation you require. Is it linear between each pair of input points that should produce 2 more points in between?

Comment: Szynon i explained it in the end after edited. The rule or the idea is : That in the first itertion the method should return a list of 4 points.  clouds lenght is 2 and i give the number 2 to the method. So first itertion the method return a list of 4 points. And then each next itertion the list should be get bigger the lenght by more 3 points. 4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28.....Just like the formula.

Comment: You keep saying the same things multiple number of times. This doesn't help, just makes reading annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> Now the method get the two points and the number 2 thats mean the method should implent between each two given points another two points

Yet your loop condition says, that for `m` in-between points you generate `m-2`:

```
for (double d = 1; d < numberOfPoints - 1; d++)
```

If for `m = 2` you want two points to be generated it should read:

```
for (double d = 1; d <= numberOfPoints; d++)
```

And inside the loop you should probably scale `d` with `(double)(numberOfPoints + 1)` instead of `(double)(numberOfPoints - 1)`.